# Jquery fadeOut does not stay hidden

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I want to fade out a div on scroll with jquery.
When it fades out it directly fades back in. It only has to fade back in when its less than 20. Otherwise stay hidden.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
$( window ).on("load", function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop()>20)
  {
   $("#intro").fadeOut();
  }
  else
{
 $('#intro').fadeIn();
};
});
});
```

Comment: This code should work, the only thing I can think of is that when you use `fadeOut`, it applies `display: none` at the end and will cause the element to be removed from the layout - if it's a large element and is the first item on the page, this could have the unintended side effect of resetting the scroll position to a number less than the threshold

Comment: Yes! Worked with animate opacity.